# chrome is forcing https error for css and js files(Error - ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)

Tags: asp.net, iis

Facing ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, while loading css and js files in chrome browser.

While loading login.aspx page related css and js files are loading in IE and Mozilla where as in chrome its not loading. We have deployed the existing application in new server, same application is working on different server. Is there any configuration to be modified in IIS? I have verified both the environment which looks identical, any specific related configuration is helpful. please find the screen shot below

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5g2z.png)

Answer (score 0):

ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID is a very popular SSL error during loading the website. In most cases, the issue is due to certificate misconfiguration on a server. However, it may appear due to antivirus and firewall or aother third-party extensions. so you can try the following methods to solve the problem.

- Check date and time are proper

  Your Chrome browser will show ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error in case the date and time are wrong on your computer or mobile device. Please recheck and adjust it on your via PC settings.
- Check browser extensions

  In some cases, the problematic browser extension could be a reason for the error. First of all, try to open the website in Incognito window and if that solves the issue then no need to check extensions. Otherwise, follow the next steps:

  1.Click the "three dots" button on the top right corner of your browser window

  2.Select More tools and Extensions

  3.Turn off extensions one by one to find culprit extension and delete it to fix the browser error.
- Check Installed SSL certificate

  In Chrome, you have to click to the "Not Secure" button located on the left side of the address bar, and then click to "Certificate". There you will see the details of SSL certificate using the field "issued to".
- Clear the SSL cache

  The browser's SSL cache can be an issue. You have to try clearing the cache to resolve the error. click "Three dots" button on the top right side of the browser, find the "Settings". There you will find "Advanced settings" at the bottom of a page. Now find "Open Proxy Settings" and there you will see the "Content" tab with "Clear SSL state"